# Why the discrepancy in price and supply between Golden Retrievers and Labrador Retrievers?

Tags: dogs, breeds

The reason I ask this question is that Golden Retriever's are booked until 2022 and they're much more expensive (3000$+) than Labrador Retrievers, which are comparatively MUCH cheaper (1500$ - literally half the cost of a Golden) but they're so readily available. There are at least five breeders right now on [Gooddog.com](https://www.gooddog.com/) that have puppies that are unreserved while being health-checked to the same degree as Goldens.

The supply of Labrador Retrievers and their cost compared to Goldens is making me question if there's some issue with Labrador Retrievers over Golden. Okay, granted Golden's a comparatively *just a little bit cuter*, but they shed more than Labrador Retrievers. I'm not sure I understand what's going on with this breed.

I've Googled and YouTubed answers for this, but I'm not convinced as to what really warrants a near 50% price difference and a much more readily available supply.

Comment: it is like everywhere in capitalism: things, which more people want, are more expensive. And things, which more people know, more people want. This is how advertisement works. Golden Retriever are selled as the incarnation of a family-dog. Labrador Retriever are not so well known, but not less able to be a family-dog. And there is a point, that dark colored dogs are less wanted by the common people than bright colors. (Shelters know this effect for example, there are initiatives to help especially dark colored dogs to find a new home) Because I have no sources, this is a comment ;)

Comment: Add to that the implicit bias of people looking for a puppy: Something "Golden" always sounds more valuable and desirable than something "Labrador". Even if people aren't aware of this bias, it still affects them. [Studies](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/08/170814092949.htm) have shown that our brains actually react to the implication that something must be more valuable by making appear even better.

Comment: It makes sense, another example is how people have an obsession about the expensive golden rings, necklaces, etc. while labrador rings and necklaces aren't even a thing because apparently nobody wants them.

Comment: This seems like a money and pet question that can go in https://money.stackexchange.com/questions as well